# How to implement a scrollview in playn game?

Tags: java, gwt, scrollview, playn

I need to use a scroll view on an Image Layer, such that the buttons on the image Layer should scroll on touch/click and move.

I have created Image Layer, buttons on it. How can I make it scroll-able?

Thank in anticipation.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this? i have everything set up really nicely with ImageLayers but am wondering if i have to swich to an ImmediateLayer or a SurfaceLayer to actually scroll it?

Comment: I couldnt find any built in widget for this. I have done it using the Pointer Listener, manually. But it wont take the pace which we scroll. Translate your Layers (which need to be scrolled. I have translated all the layers except background Layer added into a groupLayer) as you touch and drag. Also i think, Flicker class will be use full to make it better.